# My specific web.x.config file is not used

Tags: asp.net, database, windows, azure

I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC projet running on Windows Azure. I recently upgraded all packages of this project and it seems that my web.x.config is not loaded anymore.

To be more precise, I've got three different configuration :
    - Development
    - Staging
    - Production

each one has a web.x.config where x is replaced by one of these names. When running the project I was suprised that my database connection string was pretty dull (.\SQLExpress) instead of my connection to azure.

After a long time searching on the web, I tried to move this from web.Development.config :

```
    <add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database>;User ID=<login>;Password=<pass>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
```

to web.config, removing the transform :

```
    <add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database>;User ID=<login>;Password=<pass>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

At this point my database connection string is the right one, so it seems that my web.x.config is not used when running the application. I tried to locate the settings that would let me change that but to no avail. Any idea why this is happening ?

If this is convention over configuration, my configuration has got the same name as the web.config subfile i.e config : development, file : web.development.config

Thanks,
Stéphane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforms are only made when you [publish/deploy](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) the application. So while you are running/debugging locally, it uses the web.config settings (no transform is being made).

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386069/304683) for a possible solution (I haven't tried/needed personally).

Hth.

Answer (score 1):

@EdSF is correct Web.config transforms will only be applied during a publish/deploy routine not in a debug mode.

You could use an add-on like [SlowCheetah](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/12/SlowCheetahXMLTransformsFromACIServer.aspx) to apply your transforms in debug mode.