# Switching environments by running config transforms locally

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For debug reasons I have to change environments a lot (testing, QA, staging).  We current have transforms for configuration files which match these names I.e. someservice.qa.exe.config, web.staging.config.  Is it possible to locally run transforms for a configuration file (Windows service and WAP) which will overwrite the local config file?

Comment: why do you need to run them locally? you need to publish/package in order to apply transform.. you could preview them by right clicking.. check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/13386069/546375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can right click a web.config transform and select "Preview Transform". You can then save the preview to a file and overwrite it that way.

You can also set a local web.config transform as the default maybe? E.g. someservice.local.exe.config.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without a publish profile

Comment: You can create a publish profile: just have it push to a folder on your local machine.